# Global SharePoint Stats

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to do some research on general SharePoint usage across organisations.  Looking for global figures rather than just carrying out an analysis on our own SharePoint usage. Trying to get things like:

- Average number of sites
- Average size of instances

Can anyone help and direct me somewhere that might have these sorts of statistics?  Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: I think it's impossible. Micorsoft is the only one with the complete picture.

Comment: Even if you are a global administrator, you can only manage and view site usage under your tenant.